# Is a Javascript search less secure than using a search client like Sphinx or Elasticsearch?

Tags: javascript, django, elasticsearch, sphinx, livesearch

I have a concept/security question...

Looking at the search options for Django, most recommend search databases or docker apps such as sphinx or elasticsearch. However, in my particular case I was able to create a Javascript real time search that functions just as smoothly as the sphinx one on my site and is simply using my already made django postgres models.

My questions are:
What are the upsides of using a separate app or database over a javascript search?
Are there size limitations to Javascript searches?
Are there security risks with either option?

Thank you!

Comment: Uh, define "Javascript search"? Also if you're only searching and not deleting/inserting stuff, what exactly do you fear? This question is very vague, you're asking opinions about very general designs (and we don't discuss opinions here!)

Comment: Its a general question because I'm looking for a general answer :) The information is private information for business analytics. Would using front end Java allow hackers/web archive bots to grab more info than elastic or sphinx? But really the issue is I'm new with web security and I have no idea what the risks would even be, hence the question.

Comment: Well front-end Java does not exist, since browsers don't understand Java. But server-side Javascript (which is what I assume you call "javascript search") is as secure as any other language. Don't introduce bugs or mechanisms that allow code injection, and you're good.

Comment: Well sphinx and elasticsearch, etc, come with lots of 'features' that means you dont have to code them from scratch. That is the main benefit. they've already done the hard work. BUt if you have a functional solution, you probably have relatively simple requirements, in which case a seperate solution would be overkill - lots of functions you simply dont need.